# AWS IOT: Get Thing connection status

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I currently have a bunch or things registered in the AWS IOT console. i am building a web-page that will list things and display attributes from each things shadow. i am struggling to understand how do i know if a thing is currently online in (near) real time. I am retrieving the things using the **PHP SDK**

```
IotClient->listThings()
```

---

I am displaying their attributes using

```
IotDataPlaneClient->getThingShadow()
```

and

```
IotDataPlaneClient->updateThingShadow()
```

to update the shadow and this is all working fine.

But i have no way of knowing Whether or not a thing is online at a the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Fleet Indexing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-index.html) to track status of connectivity.

The information indexed per Thing:
`{name:connectivity.timestamp, type:Number},
 {name:connectivity.version, type:Number},
 {name:connectivity.connected, type:Boolean}`

*Remember the clientId used to connect **must** also exist as a Thing in the Thing registry.

Comment: Thanks Brian i will have a look at that and get back to you

Comment: ok i have implemented a solution based on fleet indexing. there is one problem though if the device unexpectedly goes offline (eg. loss of power) it takes between 5-10 mins for connectivity.connected to change to false.

Answer (score 0):

a bit expensive solution I use: I have 2 lambda that writing on the shadow when the device connects or disconnects, looking at the topic $aws/events/presence/connected/+ / $aws/events/presence/disconnected/+